# Gnome terminal losing text selection highlight after select text in another application window

Tags: gnome-terminal

In my ubuntu 17.10 Gnome terminal, I can double-click or drag&drop to select text and it will highlight the selection.

The problem is: it will lose highlight after doing text selection in another application, e.g., Google Chrome. This makes it hard to find where is my last selection in a plenty text terminal screen.

Does anyone know how to disable this annoying feature?

Comment: Don't do a left mouse click inside the window where text is highlighted. That puts it in the mode to select new text as with any operating system.

Comment: Do you mean this: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=759404?

Comment: @stumblebee Actually I was doing mouse click in another application window like Chrome. And my question title was not accurate, actually terminal highlight only disappear after doing text selection but not "paste" in another window.

Comment: @egmont Yes, it seems the same problem. Maybe a little difference: my problem is gnome-terminal losing selected text after doing selection even in another application window, not only another terminal tab.

Comment: @fubuc Now I understand after your edit. Same issue here.  I guess we wait and see what the Gnome Gods do with [Bug 759404](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=759404). Credit to [egmont](https://askubuntu.com/users/398785/egmont)

Comment: @stumblebee Yes... BTW, for now, I found a workaround but only for vim (take over mouse click interaction from gnome-terminal) : 1. `:set mouse=a`  2. `:set clipboard=unnamedplus` (vim-gnome need) 3. `:nnoremap <silent> <2-LeftMouse> :let @/='\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '\').'\>'<cr>:set hls<cr>:let @+=expand('<cword>')<cr>` ( from: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11910)

Comment: @fubupc It's ok to post a answer your own question so that others can benefit from the work-around.

Comment: Well this is annoying... I thought it was just a timeout, but it does appear to be simply the act of selecting even a single character of text in any application, even if the terminal that has selected text is in a hidden tab.  So this bug is still here as of 2022.